# How to connect to an Azure SQL Server using command prompt?

Tags: sql, database, azure-sql-database, sqlcmd, sql-server-2017

I have an Azure SQL database that I am able to connect using local SSMS.

```
Server Name - <Server>.database.windows.net
UserName - zrana
Password - *****
```

[image]

The authentication mode I use is here is Active Directory - Password. Is it possible to connect to the database using the `sqlcmd` utility on the command line?

I am unable to connect using the following command

```
sqlcmd -S 910005-sql.database.windows.net -d 900046 -U zrana -P ****
```

There is another database that I created on Azure and tried to connect through Local SSMS.

This time the authentication method is "SQL Server password". I am able to connect to it using local SSMS and through `sqlcmd` using the same format mentioned above.

Is it possible to connect to an Azure SQL database using AAD? I tried using -G -I options in my command and didn't work.

This is the error I see:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication says v15+ - do you have the latest sqlcmd ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: No, it is not the latest version. Let me update it.

Comment: @CaiusJard I updated the sqlcmd and the ODBC driver as well for sqlserver 17. I see the same error

Comment: What exact command lines have you tried (link to in depth docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15 )

Comment: It still picked the sqlcmd utility from the old ODBC driver location. I had to update the paths and it now connects using sqlcmd. Thanks @CaiusJard

Comment: Also, the other thing I had to do was use the option -G in my sqlcmd statement along with username and password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Adding an answer that is essentially the process we worked through in the comments)

1. Install the latest sqlcmd from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15
2. run `sqlcmd -?` to see what version of sqlcmd is actually running - if it isn't the latest version you just downloaded, check your PATH variable etc. You can use the dos command `where sqlcmd` to find where the command line is searching for sqlcmd
3. run sqlcmd with the -G switch to specify AAD cred checking, and include your user name an dpassword with the -U and -P options. Be careful with the case of these as -u and -p are different switches entirely.

```
sqlcmd -S 910005-sql.database.windows.net -d 900046 -G -U zrana -P ****
```

Comment: That's what I exactly did. Thank you for summarizing it.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use an Azure Active Directory user name and password, you need to provide the -G option and also use the user name and password by providing the -U and -P options. On the -U option please see on my example you need to provide the username@domain,

When using the -G option to connect to SQL Database or SQL Data Warehouse and authenticate using Azure Active Directory, a timeout value of at least 30 seconds is recommended. Use "-l 30". Read more about it on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation.

Please see the following example:

```
sqlcmd -S Target_DB_or_DW.testsrv.database.windows.net -G -U bob@contoso.com -P MyAADPassword -l 30
```